# Now that "Activity" is gone from Safari, how do I find and download a streaming flv file on a Mac?

Tags: software-recommendation, safari, google-chrome, internet, plugins

Is there a plugin (for any browser) anyone can recommend? An app?

It seems like all browsers got rid of this easy resource tracking feature (Chrome too).

Answer (score 5):

You can see still browse resources in the web inspector.

[image]

To download a file, you can copy the URL from the right sidebar, paste it on the location bar, and press ⌥↩.

The web inspector can be shown by pressing ⌥⌘I if you've enabled showing the develop menu in the advanced preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try Firebug for Firefox.

Comment: Video DownloadHelper on FireFox seems to work... though the old "Activity" function in safari was much nicer, as you could see the actual files being requested and downloaded. -- Why would newer browsers take away this vital feature? I want to be able to see what my browser is doing, what it's downloading.

Comment: It's not vital, 95% percent of the users don't care about it :) They probably broke this feature when changing to a multi-threaded mode and didn't want to lose time on something only a handful of people in the world would use.

Comment: I also suspect it was removed for precisely the reason you asked your original question - a few technical users were able to use the Activity window to download content that wasn't supposed to be downloaded (high-res pics on Flickr, streaming videos, etc).  That's purely conjecture on my part, of course.  +1 for DownloadHelper on Firefox, only reason I still have FF installed.

Comment: Flashgot! That's my favorite download tool. Made by the developer of NoScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind payware, I have Jaksta and it downloads just about any non-DRMed streaming videos. Simply go to the webpage with the video and it'll detect and download it from the beginning, you can close the browser tab once it's started and it'll continue to download., it'll even name the video after the page title.

http://www.jaksta.com/download-video-for-mac/

Answer (score 0):

Just tried Video Download Helper that did exactly what I needed, mainly it was to identify the source URL of the FLVs but it also downloaded the FLVs themselves fairly painlessly.

Recommended. I know someone has also mentioned it but I thought it deserved its own answer as Firebug is not the primary tool you need here.